# Global Scope and initialization

Tags: oop, initialization

Is it genuinely bad practice to initialize variables in the global scope? I know I could always initialize them in the constructor but I'm just wondering about general practices.

For Example
Global Scope Initialization:

```
class Foo
{
   private string foobar = "BarFoo"
   public Foo() 
   {
       ....
   }
}
```

vs Initializing in the Constructor:

```
class Foo
{
   private string foobar;
   public Foo() 
   {
       foobar = "BarFoo" ;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should try to justify placing any variable in the Global scope.  The reason you should justify is that it is very easy to add and use variables in the Global scope **but very difficult to find, reproduce and fix the types of side-effect errors that arise from their "over-use".**

Comment: @DavidTansey He's asking about the initialization, not the declaration. In this case, I see no reason why you'd initialize in the constructor, unless you wanted to set the variable's value to something that was injected via constructor.

Comment: I agree completely, I used strings as a very basic example but say I am maintaining a collection that more than one method in the class will modify. I don't want to be passing it around the world making copies in memory everywhere so I make a global variable for it. What is the difference between initializing it in the global scope vs. the constructor?